# How to export the high resolution animation movie?

Tags: graphics, export, image, animation

I would like to export high resolution animation
Here is the code:

```
animate=Table[Graphic[...]];
rasterizedFrames = Map[Image, animate];
Export["movie.mov", rasterizedFrames];
```

I first generate a Animator table, then Use Image to map it. With this way, the resolution of the movie is very bad. The resolution usually is defined in Image or Export function. How could I put in it?
The reason I am not directly export the animation is it always claim an error (out of memory)

Comment: In your Table expression, use `Image[#, ImageResolution -> desiredDPIvalue]&` instead of plain `Image`.